# Dynamic Division not generated on click event in phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I have a link .

```
 <a href="#">Handcrafted AMG 4.0L biturbo V-8</a>
```

On clicking this link a new division is displayed:

```
<div class="desc cloned">
    <div class="wrap">                                             
        <div class="desc_wrap">
            <div class="heading">Handcrafted AMG 4.0L biturbo V-8</div>
            <div class="price">Standard</div>
            <div class="text">Some Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code which I have written is:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElementFeature = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Handcrafted AMG 4.0L biturbo V-8"));
if (WebElementFeature.isEnabled() && WebElementFeature.isDisplayed()) {
    jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].click;",WebElementFeature);
}
```

This code is working fine in firefox driver but when I change to phantomjs driver it is not working.